# c# Dictionary to Json and Dictionary to Dictionary, how?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I trying to do Dictionary with access as dictionary["1"] -> "Some":

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> dictionary { get; private set; } = new();
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);

json ={
  "1": "Some",
  "2222": "Data",
  "4123": "In",
  "107": "That",
  "4213213": "Json"
}
```

after, I want read it:

```
string fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
dictionary = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(fileContents);
```

and getting error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})

I tried:

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary.ToArray());
```

with json output

```
[
  {
    "Key": "1",
    "Value": "Some"
  },
  {
    "Key": "2222",
    "Value": "Data"
  }
]
```

and after

```
dictionary = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(fileContents);
```

getting the same error. Where Is a mistake?

Comment: check string fileContents= sr.ReadToEnd(); You have a bug there, the file must be empty

Comment: I have a very hard time believing that the JSON you provided in your first code block is the one that is actually being read by the second code block and producing the error in the third code block. The error states that it can't deserialize a JSON array to a dictionary, but the JSON you provided in the first code block is not an array and does not contain an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what contains string fileContents= sr.ReadToEnd(); IMHO You have a bug there, the file must be contains the previous json or a corrupted text.

After you fix it , then for the second case instead of a dictionary it is more efficient to use a KeyValuePair list

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>(json);
```

or you can still use a dictionary, but only  a list of dictionaries

```
var dictionary = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
```

Comment: If the file was empty, it would not be throwing the error that the OP said it is. If the file was empty it would simply be deserialized to `null`.

Comment: Response to edit: "corrupted text" also would not cause the error the OP posted. The only way that error would be thrown is if and only if the JSON is a valid array. The only explanation here is that for whatever reason, the OP did not provide the JSON that is actually being read by this code and throwing the error. That alone makes this question unclear (and off-topic). I'm sure you've been around long enough to know that unclear questions 90% of the time result in unclear answers. This one is no exception.